# MST that differ only on one edge

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have stack to the following problem

Let $\,\mathbf{G=\left(V,E\right)}$ be a graph with a weight function $\mathbf{w:E\rightarrow\mathbb R}$ such that

1. **G is simple,connected and undirected**
2. **w is injective**
3. $\mathbf{\exists x\exists y\in V:f=\{x,y\}\notin E}$

Let $\,\mathbf{G'=\left(V',E'\right)}$ be a graph with a weight function $\mathbf{w':E'\rightarrow\mathbb R}$ such that

1. $\mathbf{V'=V,E'=E\cup\{f\}}$
2. $\mathbf{w'\left(e\right)=w\left(e\right),\forall\mathbf e\in E}$
3. $\mathbf{w'\left (f\right)<min \,w\left(T\right)}$ where **T** is the **unique minimum spanning tree (MST) of G** and $\mathbf{w\left(T\right)=\{w\left(e\right):e\in E\left( T\right)\}}$

**Show that**

$\mathbf{\left (i\right )} $$\,\mathbf G' $ **has a unique (MST) , T'**

$\mathbf{\left (ii\right )}$ **T and T' differ at only one edge**

I have shown $\mathbf{\left (i\right )}$ and that **T'** must **contain f** instead of **ε** which is **the unique edge of maximum weight on the unique cycle** of $\mathbf{T\cup\{f\}}$.

But how do i show that **T,T' have all other edges in common**?I can show that using for instance **Prim's algorithm** but is there another way,more theoretical without a use of all known MST-finding algorithms?

**Thank You**

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be the unique circuit in $T\cup \{f\}$ and $e\in E(C)$ be the edge with maximal weight in $C$.

Notice that any MST $T'$ of $G'$ either contains $f$ or does not contain $f$. If it does not contain $f$ then we claim it is not an MST. If it does, we claim $T' = T\cup \{f\} \setminus \{e\}$. This solves (i) and (ii).

Indeed, if $T'$ does not contain $f$ then it is also a spanning tree of $G$.
By the uniqueness of $T$, $T$ has less weight than $T'$.
But $T$ is also an MST of $G'$, contradicting that $T'$ was an MST.

If it does contain $f$, then $T'-f$ has two connected subtrees.
Let $S, \bar{S}\subseteq V(G)$ be the vertices of these subtrees and note that their disjoint union is exactly $V(G)$, ie $(S, \bar{S})$ induces a cut of $G$.
Then $T'[S], T'[\bar{S}]$, the induced trees are MSTs of their respective induced subgraphs $G'[S], G'[S']$.
Remark that $G'[S] = G[S], G'[\bar{S}] = G[\bar{S}]$ since the two graphs only differ by an edge crossing the cut $(S, \bar{S})$.
But then $T'[S], T'[\bar{S}]$ must be the unique MSTs of their respective induced subgraphs since $T$ was unique. In other words, $T'[S] = T[S], T'[\bar{S}] = T[\bar{S}]$.

This shows that any MST of $G'$ must contain $f$. Moreover, when we remove $f$ and look at the two subgraphs of $G'$ induced by the vertices of the two connected components of $T'-f$, any MST of $G'$ does not differ from the unique MST of $G$.
Any MST of $G$ or $G'$ can only have one edge in the cut $(S, \bar{S})$. For $T'$, this edge is $f$.
For $T'$, this is not $f$ since $f$ does not exist in $G$.

Comment: The only thing u showed is that $T'\left[ S\right],T'\left[\bar S\right]$ are the unique MST's of the induced subgraphs $G\left[S\right],G\left[\bar S\right]$.Why this implies that the unique MST of $G$ ,$T$ differ from $T'$ only by one side?

Comment: I added a few sentences to my answer.

Comment: Now u r talking.Thank u.You were so helpful